# Add Fragment on another fragment

Tags: android

I want to achieve below concept in android:-

```
Tab A -> Fragment A -> Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2
Tab B -> Fragment B
Tab C -> Fragment C
Tab D -> Fragment D
```

I am adding tabs on view pager and able to achieve till

```
Tab A -> Fragment A
Tab B -> Fragment B
Tab C -> Fragment C
Tab D -> Fragment D
```

I tried with

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

but not able to add another fragment on `Fragment A`.

it is adding fragment 1 upon `Fragment A` but `Fragment A` is still visible in background. So please provide some suggestion to achieve above task.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should apply a transparent background color to your container and parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's mine. Hope it's helpful.

First, you need to create the ContentFragment for 4 tabs A, B, C, D like below:

```
public class ContentFragmentA extends BaseFragment {
private static Context context;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public ContentFragmentA(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_frame_a, container, false);

    this.setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager());
    this.setContainerId(R.id.content_frame_a);

    this.replaceFragmentIntoStack(new FragmentOne(context), "FragmentOne");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}}
```

Then, create the content_fragment_a.xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_frame_a"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Then, for each new fragment you should extends **BaseFragment**. And when if you want to put new fragment into tab, just use *addFragmentIntoStack()*, or *replaceFragmentIntoStack()*.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


private int containerId;
private boolean doubleBackToExit = false;
/**
 * @param containerId the containerId to set
 */
public void setContainerId(int containerId) {
    this.containerId = containerId;
}

/**
 * @param fragmentManager the fragmentManager to set
 */
public void setFragmentManager(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public BaseFragment() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    BarddyApplication.getInstance().baseFragment = BaseFragment.this;
}

public void addFragmentIntoStack(BaseFragment newContent, String tagName) {
    newContent.setFragmentManager(fragmentManager);
    newContent.setContainerId(containerId);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(containerId, newContent, tagName);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tagName);

    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

public void popFragment() {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
}

public void replaceFragmentIntoStack(BaseFragment newContent, String tagName) {
    newContent.setFragmentManager(fragmentManager);
    newContent.setContainerId(containerId);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId,newContent,tagName);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple!
Fist you need to fragment A blank and then you need create new three fragment:
Fragment A1, fragment 1, fragmen2
And now when you chose tab A, you show fragment A1 in fragment A

```html
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction();

  transaction.replace(R.id.category_fragment, new CategoryFragment());

  transaction.commit();
```

Now you can use method replace() fragment 1 or 2 to id of Fragment A (not id of A1) to replace A1 with fragment 1 or 2.
Hope it help you!